# Problems with GET method

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Aplicatie</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <label>Carnet Student:</label>
    <input id="carnetstudent">
    <button onclick="checkForCarnetStudent()">Verifica</button>
    <br>
    <p id="response"></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Carnet Student:</label>
    <input id="carnetstudent_input">
    <br>
    <label>Nume Student:</label>
    <input id="nume">
    <br> 
    <label>Prenume Student:</label>
    <input id="prenume">
    <br>
    <label>Nota Medie:</label>
    <input id="notamedie">
    <br> 
    <button onclick="addNew()">Adauga Student</button>
    <p id="response_input"></p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
  <script>
   function checkForCarnetStudent() {
  var carnetstudent = document.getElementById('carnetstudent').value;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(carnetstudent)) {
          document.getElementById('response').textContent = JSON.stringify(data[carnetstudent]);
        } else {
          document.getElementById('response').textContent = "Studentul nu a fost gasit in baza de date";
        }
      } else {
        document.getElementById('response').textContent = "Eroare la cererea GET catre server";
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/student?carnetstudent=" + carnetstudent , true);
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
<script>
  function addNew() {
    var carnetstudent_input = document.getElementById('carnetstudent_input').value;
    var nume = document.getElementById('nume').value;
    var prenume = document.getElementById('prenume').value;
    var notamedie = document.getElementById('notamedie').value;

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('carnetstudent', carnetstudent_input);
    formData.append('nume', nume);
    formData.append('prenume', prenume);
    formData.append('notamedie', notamedie);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          document.getElementById('response_input').textContent = "Studentul a fost adaugat cu succes";
        } else {
          document.getElementById('response_input').textContent = "Eroare la cererea POST către server";
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/student", true);
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got this page code and this is the server side of it on python:

```
import os
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

students = {}

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_response(self, status_code=200, headers=None):
        self.send_response(status_code)
        if headers is not None:
            for header, value in headers.items():
                self.send_header(header, value)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/' or os.path.basename(self.path) == 'http_local_client.html':
            file_path = 'C:/Users/asdga/Desktop/f/f/http_local_client.html'
            try:
                with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                    self._set_response()
                    self.wfile.write(file.read().encode('utf-8'))
            except FileNotFoundError:
                self._set_response(status_code=404)
                self.wfile.write(b'Fisierul nu a fost gasit')
        elif self.path.startswith('/student'):
            query_string = self.path.split('?')
            if len(query_string) > 1:
                params = parse_qs(query_string[1])
                carnet_student = params.get('carnetstudent', [''])[0]

                if carnet_student in students:
                    student_data = students[carnet_student]
                    self._set_response(headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
                    response_data = json.dumps(student_data)
                    self.wfile.write(response_data.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    self._set_response(status_code=404)
                    self.wfile.write(b'Studentul nu a fost gasit')
            else:
                self._set_response(status_code=400)
                self.wfile.write(b'Bad request: Missing query parameters')
        else:
            self._set_response(status_code=404)
            self.wfile.write(b'Pagina nu a fost gasita')


    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/student' or self.path == '/student/':
            content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
            form_data = self.rfile.read(content_length).decode('utf-8')
            parsed_data = parse_qs(form_data)
            carnet_student = parsed_data.get('carnetstudent', [''])[0]
            nume = parsed_data.get('nume', [''])[0]
            prenume = parsed_data.get('prenume', [''])[0]
            nota_medie = parsed_data.get('notamedie', [''])[0]

            students[carnet_student] = {
                'nume': nume,
                'prenume': prenume,
                'notamedie': nota_medie
            }

            self._set_response()
            self.wfile.write(b'Studentul a fost adaugat cu succes')
        else:
            self._set_response(status_code=404)
            self.wfile.write(b'Pagina nu a fost gasita')


def run_server(port=8080):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, RequestHandler)
    print(f'Serverul ruleaza pe portul {port}')
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server()
```

Now whenever I click on my "Add Students" button everything works just good and it seems like it has been registered, however  when I want to check it by its number I get "Error at GET method towards server" and nothing more. How can I make it work, I have it ran on the local server "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"

I ve tried everything I know but nothing seemed to work

Comment: check your logs

Comment: I get this: 
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: if i were u i would try to debug the python code, there are several place where you will return a 404 not found, my bet is that `if carnet_student in students` is FALSE and therefore returning 404 not found

Comment: Well how can I make that statement true and make it work